# How can I change the default version of Python Used by Atom?

Tags: python, python-3.x, editor, atom-editor

I have started using Atom recently and for the past few days, I have been searching on how to change the default version used in Atom (The default version is currently python 2.7 but I want to use 3.6). Is there anyone I can change the default path? (I have tried adding a profile to the "script" package but it still reverts to python 2.7 when I restart Atom. Any help will be hugely appreciated!! Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: are you using virtual environments? If not, how do you run with 2 versions of python (2.7 and 3,6.  If you are using virtual environments, just activate the one for the version of python you want to use.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, well I’m not sure If I’m using Environments is there any way to check? (PS: I’m currently using to Coderunner 2 on my mac to code in Python) @jmh

Comment: How did you install python? Using homebrew?  Anaconda?  MacPorts? Directly from Python.org?  Do you remember?

Comment: if you don't know try typing 'brew list' at command prompt.  You should get a list of packages installed by homebrew. If python is listed you MAY have installed it using homebrew.

Comment: @jmh I’m pretty sure I downloaded it directly from Python.org (probably wasn’t the best choice

Comment: @jmh it isn’t listed in brew list, should I install it through brew?

Comment: that's fine.  Many people do it that way.  It is considered wise to use virtual environments when using more than one version of python.  You have 2.7.15, probably, installed and I suppose you installed version 3.6?  I 'm probably not the right person to help you.  If you had installed it using Anaconda I could help you better.  My first suggestion would be to create virtual environments, one for python 2.7 and one for Python 3.6. Then activate the version you want to use.

Comment: @jmh do you have an idea how I could creat an environment and will it affect the packages that I currently have installed?

Comment: you can google 'python virtual environments' to see how to create them. you'll get hundreds of hits.  What is wrong with code runner?  you said you were using that.

Comment: @jmh nothing wrong, great mac app. The thing is that other editors such as atom have a lot of features in contrast CodeRunner hasn’t many. So I thought that It might be interesting to shift.

Comment: Unless you need this ASAP i'd wait for an answer on this site before I'd proceed. If it's urgent I'll try to help but it'll take awhile.  We'll start getting warnings soon about too many comments.

Comment: @jmh no worries it isn’t urgent, Thanks a ton for your help. I will google and look arround on how to set an Environment. If you don’t mind me asking what Editor to you use?

Comment: I use Atom or Visual Studio Code.  I have actually played with many. I am still just learning python and I'm a super geek, so playing with all these editors was fun.  haha.  I'm not sick just geeky with a lot of free time.

Answer (score 10):

I am using **script 3.18.1** in **Atom 1.32.2**

Navigate to Atom (at top left) > Open Preferences > Open Config folder.

Now, Expand the tree as script > lib > grammars

Open **python.coffee** and change 'python' to 'python3' in both the places in command argument

Comment: This worked for me just two points to add:
Expand tree as Packages > script > lib > grammars

and after changing python to python 3 restart atom to see changes taking effect.

Comment: I had to edit `python.js` in `/Users/bryanhanson/.atom/packages/script/lib/grammars` in Atom 1.56 on Mac BigSur, and Script 3.31.1  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I would look in the atom installed plugins in settings.. you can get here by pressing command + shift + p, then searching for settings.

The only reason I suggest this is because, plugins is where I installed swift language usage accessibility through a plugin that manages that in atom.

Other words for plugins on atom would be "community packages"

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have a python package but sadly there isn't any way to change the path nor the version of python I want Atom to use

Comment: @Fozoro If you can , @ me in the answer when its found.

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. After starting Atom, open the script you wish to run. Then open command palette and select 'Python: Select interpreter'. A list appears with the available python versions listed. Select the one you want and hit return. Now you can run the script by placing the cursor in the edit window and right-clicking the mouse. A long menu appears and you should choose the 'Run python in the terminal window'. This is towards the bottom of the long menu list. The script will run using the interpreter you selected.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an inelegant solution that may not be universal.  Using platformio-ide-terminal, I simply had to call python3.9 instead of python or python3.  Not sure if that is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31181244)