# Problem with importing python modules on Atom

Tags: python, atom-editor

Upon trying to use the requests module I just downloaded, Atom displayed an error message that stated the module cannot be found. However, in the Mac OS terminal, the module is imported with no problem.

I looked at the results I obtained after calling sys.path, and it seems that the Atom text editor is using Python2.7 whereas the module is downloaded to Python3 folder. How do I change this?

I have already changed the script package's default version to python3 as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50667214/how-can-i-change-the-default-version-of-python-used-by-atom).

The problem seems to be in the interpreter path. When I call sys.path in the terminal, I get this:

[terminal path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoS1o.png)

But on Atom, I get:

```
['/Users/berk/Desktop/Vaccine',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', 
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', 
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', 
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', 
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', 
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', 
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the default version of Python Used by Atom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50667214/how-can-i-change-the-default-version-of-python-used-by-atom)

Comment: You're using the `script` package, right? I'm assuming so. BTW welcome to SO! Check ou the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: I have already changed the script package to python3.

Comment: Then check `sys.version`

Comment: OK, I see. Please include that in the question. Did you put a shebang in your script? If so, what is it?

Comment: And just to make sure, you are using `script` to run the file, right? Not another package like `script-runner` or something?

Comment: No other package. sys.version is displaying python 3.9 on my terminal but 2.7 on Atom. I tried using the shebang #!/usr/bin/python3.9 but it failed

Comment: What do you mean by "failed"? You need to include this info in the question.

Comment: I received the error message: Unable to run
/usr/bin/python3.9
Did you start Atom from the command line?
  atom .
Is it in your PATH?
PATH: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbi

Comment: Does `/usr/bin/python3.9` actually exist?